# Airdrop not working

Tags: wifi, airdrop

Occasionaly I need to transfer files between laptops (when I don't have internet for example). Through my experience Airdrop actually worked less than 5% of the time, the other 95% the devices never show up on each other airdrop finder window. Not even after I connected both computers to the same router.

I find it extremely unreliable! I have 3 Apple devices at home: a Mid-2014 15inch MBP, a Early-2015 13inch MBP and an iPad Air2.

The laptops were 10 cm apart, both wireless were turned on and even with the iPad no device was showing up. I am wondering what am I doing wrong?

Even at work when trying to use airdrop between coworkers' laptops no laptop was showing up on Airdrop.

I live fine without Airdrop as I almost always have internet, but I would like for it to work in the rare occasions that I am offline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AirDrop is very hit and miss. Sometimes, it can work consistently for a day, other times, it won't work for a week. I have issues with it all the time. I'm hoping this gets resolved in iOS 10 and OS X 10.12 this fall.

Comment: I'm hoping it gets resolved in iOS 18 and macOS 15 when they come out next year

Answer (score 1):

As ComputerScienceStudent said, AirDrop is indeed very finicky.

Check your visibility status. I forget this more often than I'd like, but it happens. Ensure that your visibility status is not set to "Contacts Only" but set to "Everyone". This can be done on an iDevice by heading to Control Center and ensuring that AirDrop at the bottom is set to "Everyone" or on a Mac, ensuring that "Allow me to be discovered by" is set to "Everyone".

[image: Control Center]

Comment: I did that every time but it never solved my problem